# How are python imports reused

Tags: python-3.x, import

If I have a package, does it not matter where or how I import external packages as far as performance is concerned? specifically, if I import a package, say numpy, in every file independently, is that just as fast as importing numpy in one file and from that file importing that numpy instance into every other file?

as a test I mocked up this simple example:

```
package
---file1.py
---file2.py
---file3.py
```

with

```
file1.py
========
import time
start = time.time()
import numpy as np
print("file1 loaded numpy in {}".format(time.time() - start))
def func():
    return None

file2.py
========
import time
start = time.time()
import numpy as np
print("file2 loaded numpy in {}".format(time.time() - start))
def func():
    return None


file3.py
========
import file1
import file2
import time
start = time.time()
import numpy as np
print("file3 loaded numpy in {}".format(time.time() - start))
```

which, when I run file3.py, gets output

```
file1 loaded numpy in 0.08520007133483887
file2 loaded numpy in 7.152557373046875e-07
file2 loaded numpy in 4.76837158203125e-07
```

This suggests to me that it doesn't matter if you reimport things since clearly file2 and file3 were using a cache of the numpy instance loaded in file1.
My question then is - is this always true? Or is there some conceivable configuration in which I will be reloading entire packages, internal or external, from scratch?